# Ingress in GKE does not do the routing identically despite same IP at DNS level

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have setup in my GKE cluster an nginx ingress as follows:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace nginx-ingress
```

A load balancer with its IP came up.

Now I added two DNS pointing to that domain at Cloudflare:

[image]

In addition I created a namespace `app-a`

```
kubectl create namespace app-a
kubectl label namespace app-a project=a
```

and deployed an app there:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo1
  namespace: app-a
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo1
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo1
  namespace: app-a
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo1
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo1
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        args:
        - "-text=echo1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5678
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress-global
  namespace: app-a
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "test.my-domain.com"
    http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: echo1
              port:
                number: 80
```

Things look good in Lens, so I thought to test it out.

When I was entering `eu1.my-domain.com`, I get

[image]

which is intended, of course.

but when I entered `test.my-domain.com`, I get that the website is unreachable: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`, although I expected to see the dummy output of the dummy app.

Even more strangely, no matter if I get the well-responding result or the non-responding one, in the logs of the nginx controller there is nothing showing up for any of the calls.

Can you help me, such that I can access the `test.my-domain.com` homepage?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but to networking, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you change the PathType from Prefix to ImplementationSpecific in the Ingress object and see if it works ?